# Set value of input field and submit on page load

Tags: javascript, onclick, input-field

Onclick of a `<button>` I would to fill in the value of an input field and directly submit it. The input field looks like this:

```
<input aria-label="Ask me something..." autocomplete="off" 
placeholder="Ask me something..." autofocus="autofocus" type="text" 
class="queryform">
```

I have tried something like this but can't get it submitted:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("queryform")[0].value='Hallo Joris'
var e = new Event("keyup");
e.key='Enter';
e.keyCode=e.key.charCodeAt(13);
e.which=e.keyCode;
e.altKey=false;
e.ctrlKey=true;
e.shiftKey=false;
e.metaKey=false;
e.bubbles=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("queryform")[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

You can play around on gowogo.com

Comment: Could you just select the `<form>` and call `submit()` on it? Might be easier

Comment: Unfortunately the input is not placed in a form and I can't change that part of the code.

Comment: Might you post the site in question so we can see what's going on and experiment with solutions?

Comment: so submit the form? `var elem = document.querySelector(".queryform"); elem.value="foo" ; elem.form.submit();`

Comment: You can't submit an input field directly (where would it submit to, since there's no `action="URL"` attribute?). You'll need to use AJAX if there's no form.

Comment: I added the domain to play around. Buttons will be placed below the intro text.

Comment: Https://gowogo.com

Comment: I tried to put the input field into a form, in that case, I can submit the form, but it actually doesn't get submitted (like doing it manually) since it doesn't work together with Vue I think. I am looking now to use the @keyup.enter="submit()". And can't get anything else out the code really, like where it is posting to for example.

   <input :aria-label="config.locale.strings.queryTitle" autocomplete="off" v- 
   model="query" class="queryform" @keyup.enter="submit()" 
   :placeholder="config.locale.strings.queryTitle" autofocus type="text">